# How to do a sumproduct of values in two arrays in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am trying to do the sumproduct of two arrays in VBA as I am trying to avoid referencing the worksheet until write time due to its size and complexity.

I knwo I can use the applicationfunction to run sumproduct with defining two ranges, but that still references the worksheet, is there anyway to do it with just using arrays purely in code?

Comment: Ah thank, wondered how you did that.  I tried using the up error but it said I had too low a reputation to d it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you just call SUMPRODUCT and pass it the arrays: (but note that its a bit inefficient)

```
Sub testing2()
Dim varr1(1 To 10)
Dim varr2(1 To 10)
Dim vres As Variant
Dim j As Long
For j = 1 To 10
varr1(j) = j
varr2(j) = j * 10
Next j
vres = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(varr1, varr2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this less efficient than writing to the file?  My issue is to try and find the best possible solution to cut down on runtime speed

Comment: Also, is it possibel to do it with a subset of an existing array or only with complete array- so in your example here to use elemenst 5-10 from varr1 and then array2 would be defined with just 5 elements, or would you have to load the subset into a new array?

Comment: Its probably faster than writing to the sheet and doing the SUMPRODUCT in ythe sheet. But it works by converting the variant arrays to a format that SUMPRODUCT understands and the converiosn costs time. For the subset its probably fastest to load the sunset into a new array. But the real question is probably why are you using SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: Essentially I have a list of investments and an expected return according to type- each one has to be multiplied by its corresponding return.  Since there are twenty in each, I thought it faster ti do using a sumproduct.  Would it be faster by just multiplying each result?

Comment: Depends how the data is organised - I suggest you start timing the diffeent approaches to see which works best for you.

Comment: Thanks, guess some experimentation is in order